# Deleting node with two children in binary search tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, nodes, delete-operator

I'm trying to delete a node with two children. However, my function is not completely removing the node from the tree, leaving a duplicate.

Here are my functions:

```
void Remove(Node *&r, int idx)
{
    if(Search(r, idx))
    {
        if(idx < r->id)      Remove(r->left, idx);
        else if(idx > r->id) Remove(r->right, idx);
        else                 DeleteNode(r);

        //cout << "Account " << idx << " is now closed.";
    }
    else cout << "Account does not exist." << endl;
}

void DeleteNode(Node *&r)
{
    Node *temp = r;

    if(r->left == NULL && r->right != NULL) 
    {
        r = temp->right;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else if(r->left != NULL && r->right == NULL) 
    {
        r = temp->left; 
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else if(r->left == NULL && r->right == NULL)
    {
        r = NULL;
        delete r;
    }
    else 
    {
        // go to left of r and find largest value
        temp = FindMax(r->left);

        int    tempID        = temp->id; 
        float  tempBal       = temp->balance;
        string tempString    = temp->name; 

        DeleteNode(temp);   

        r->id = tempID; 
        r->balance = tempBal;
        r->name = tempString;
    }
}

Node* FindMax(Node *t)
{
    while(t->right != NULL) 
    {
        t = t->right;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Suppose I have this tree:

```
          33
    22          44 
11      25
```

Deleting `22` leads to this:

```
          33
    22          44 
22      25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = FindMax(r->left);
```

Not what you meant to do.  When you `DeleteNode(temp)`, the old node is still in the tree but `temp` got overwritten.  You meant to overwrite the parent's `right` member.

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit? I am still unsure by what you mean.

Comment: Your function takes a reference and overwrites the referenced pointer.  `DeleteNode(temp)` overwrites `temp` but does not change the tree.  (In other words, I don't understand what's confusing you here.)